# Inserindo Itens em uma collection Vb6

Tags: visual-basic-6, collection

Bom dia pessoal, .
A circunstancia é a seguinte. eu criei um Type e o mesmo tem seus atributos.
Gostaria de saber como eu faço para inserir dados em um collection(no Vb6).
POR EXEMPLO: criei o Type Pessoa q tem atributo de nome e sobrenome, agora preciso criar uma coleção desse type.

Answer (score 2):

Uma coleção em VB6 / VBA é do tipo Colletion e aceita qualquer objeto de referencia, uma maneira de fazer isso é no Módulo ou na sua Classe ter uma propriedade que consuma sua coleção para esse tipo específico.

Por ex:

```
Private Pessoas_ As New Colletion

Private Sub PopulaPessoas()
      Dim Pessoa1 As MeuTipoPessoa
      Dim Pessoa2 As MeuTipoPessoa
      Dim Pessoa3 As MeuTipoPessoa

      Pessoas_.Add(Pessoa1)
      Pessoas_.Add(Pessoa2)
      Pessoas_.Add(Pessoa3)
End Sub

Public Property Get Professores() As Colletion
    Dim oPessoa As MeuTipoPessoa
    Dim oColecaoRetorno As New Colletion

    For Each oPessoa In Pessoas_
        If (oPessoa.EhProfessor) Then
            oColecaoRetorno.Add(oPessoa)
        End If    
    Next
    Set Professores = oColecaoRetorno
End Property
```